# Sum of previous rows and multiply with value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with around 80000 records. Here is an example:

| startyear | division | account | budget | forecast |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 40 | 4100 | 5122952,22 | 0,012306656 |
| 2022 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,011424198 |
| 2023 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,010431491 |
| 2024 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,009311863 |
| 2025 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,008324122 |
| 2026 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,007763793 |
| 2027 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,007557735 |
| 2028 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,007357883 |
| 2029 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,007160051 |
| 2030 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006953345 |
| 2031 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006737952 |
| 2032 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006535297 |
| 2033 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006364179 |
| 2034 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006213237 |
| 2035 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,006085724 |
| 2036 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,005944279 |
| 2037 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,005758285 |
| 2038 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,005559474 |
| 2039 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,005360105 |
| 2040 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,005163794 |
| 2041 | 40 | 4100 | 0 | 0,004972228 |

I'm trying to calculate a new column starting with the budget from line 1. So year 2021 will be the same. the first calculation is correct. But the rest of the calculation ignores the changes before.
This is the code:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT startyear, division, account, forecast, SUM(budget) AS asum
FROM @table
GROUP BY startyear,
         division,
         account,
         forecast
), cteRanked AS (
SELECT cte.startyear,
             cte.division,
             cte.account,
             cte.forecast,
             cte.asum AS asum
FROM cte
)
SELECT c1.startyear,
          c1.division,
          c1.account,
          c1.forecast,
          c1.asum , ISNULL((SELECT SUM(c2.asum)*c1.forecast 
FROM cteRanked c2 
WHERE c1.startyear > 2021 
    AND c2.startyear < c1.startyear 
    AND c2.division = c1.division 
    AND c2.account = c1.account), c1.asum) AS Bud
FROM cteRanked c1
ORDER BY c1.division, c1.account, c1.startyear
```

Gives this result:

| startyear | division | account | forecast | budget | result | correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 40 | 4100 | 0,012306656 | 5122952,22 | 5122952,22 | 5122952,22 |
| 2022 | 40 | 4100 | 0,011424198 | 0 | 58525,62051 | 58525,62 |
| 2023 | 40 | 4100 | 0,010431491 | 0 | 53440,02998 | 54050,54 |
| 2024 | 40 | 4100 | 0,009311863 | 0 | 47704,22923 | 48752,52 |
| 2025 | 40 | 4100 | 0,008324122 | 0 | 42644,07928 | 43987,00 |
| 2026 | 40 | 4100 | 0,007763793 | 0 | 39773,54059 | 41367,57 |

As you can see this query does not cumulate the results when the query runs.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't get the logic you want. Please explain how column `correct` is supposed to be computed.

Comment: Ah, sorry. we start with the first row og 5122952 and multiply with row2 forecast 0,01142xx and the result is 58525. But the next row (#3) should add these 2 and multiply with the forecast for this row. and this result is 54050. As it is now it takes the budget from the first row and multiply with the forecast for each row and not adding up the prev. rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your post is lacking some vital information...I don't necessarily blame you because it's a difficult problem to both explain and to solve.

It looks like you're basically trying to come up with a compounding interest calculator. Except in this case, the rate changes every year.

To calculate the PRODUCT aggregate of your forecasts, I found this blog post:
https://blog.jooq.org/2018/09/21/how-to-write-a-multiplication-aggregate-function-in-sql/

It just required a very tiny bit of tweaking.

This is my answer:

```sql
DECLARE @StartingYear int = 2021,
        @StartingBudget decimal(12, 2);

SELECT @StartingBudget = yt.budget
FROM #YourTable yt
WHERE yt.startyear = @StartingYear

SELECT yt.startyear, yt.division, yt.account, yt.budget, yt.forecast, YearBudget = yt.budget, PrevYearDiff = yt.budget
FROM #YourTable yt
WHERE yt.startyear = @StartingYear
UNION ALL
SELECT x.startyear, x.division, x.account, x.budget, x.forecast
     , YearBudget = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), x.SumProdBudget)
     , PrevYearDiff = CONVERT(decimal(10,2), x.SumProdBudget - LAG(x.SumProdBudget,1,@StartingBudget) OVER (ORDER BY x.startyear))
FROM (
    SELECT yt.startyear, yt.division, yt.account, yt.budget, yt.forecast
        , SumProdBudget = EXP(SUM(LOG(1+yt.forecast)) OVER (ORDER BY yt.startyear)) * @StartingBudget
    FROM #YourTable yt
    WHERE yt.startyear > @StartingYear
) x
```

Returns:

```plaintext
| startyear | division | account | budget     | forecast    | YearBudget | PrevYearDiff | 
|-----------|----------|---------|------------|-------------|------------|--------------| 
| 2021      | 40       | 4100    | 5122952.22 | 0.012306656 | 5122952.22 | 5122952.22   | 
| 2022      | 40       | 4100    | 0.00       | 0.011424198 | 5181477.84 | 58525.62     | 
| 2023      | 40       | 4100    | 0.00       | 0.010431491 | 5235528.38 | 54050.54     | 
| 2024      | 40       | 4100    | 0.00       | 0.009311863 | 5284280.90 | 48752.52     | 
| 2025      | 40       | 4100    | 0.00       | 0.008324122 | 5328267.90 | 43987.00     | 
| 2026      | 40       | 4100    | 0.00       | 0.007763793 | 5369635.47 | 41367.57     |
```

The key to this whole thing is this line:

```sql
SELECT SumProdBudget = EXP(SUM(LOG(1+yt.forecast)) OVER (ORDER BY yt.startyear)) * @StartingBudget
```

This is saying to return a running product of all previous forecasts, then multiply that by the original budget. This will produce the budget for each year, technically based on the budget of the previous year.

Then once you have that, I stuck it in a sub-query to find the difference between the year and its previous year.

---

### Sample Data:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTable','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #YourTable; --SELECT * FROM #YourTable
CREATE TABLE #YourTable (
    startyear   int             NOT NULL,
    division    int             NOT NULL,
    account     int             NOT NULL,
    budget      decimal(12, 2)  NOT NULL,
    forecast    decimal(10, 9)  NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO #YourTable (startyear, division, account, budget, forecast)
VALUES (2021, 40, 4100, 5122952.22, 0.012306656)
     , (2022, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.011424198)
     , (2023, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.010431491)
     , (2024, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.009311863)
     , (2025, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.008324122)
     , (2026, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.007763793)
     , (2027, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.007557735)
     , (2028, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.007357883)
     , (2029, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.007160051)
     , (2030, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006953345)
     , (2031, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006737952)
     , (2032, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006535297)
     , (2033, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006364179)
     , (2034, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006213237)
     , (2035, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.006085724)
     , (2036, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.005944279)
     , (2037, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.005758285)
     , (2038, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.005559474)
     , (2039, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.005360105)
     , (2040, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.005163794)
     , (2041, 40, 4100, 0         , 0.004972228);
```

Comment: Hi, it seems like this is actually working. In my example I have only a few rows. The original table is 80000 records. With 18 different divisions and a few hundred accounts. I had to make some changes to your query like this:
'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tempTablePrevYearDiff = x.SumProdBudget - LAG(x.SumProdBudget,1,(SELECT SUM(t.budget) FROM #YourTable t WHERE t.division = x.division AND t.account = x.account AND t.startyear = @StartingYear)) OVER (ORDER BY x.division, x.account, x.startyear)

Comment: and 
(ORDER BY yt.division, yt.account, yt.startyear)) * (SELECT SUM(budget) FROM #YourTable t WHERE t.division = yt.division AND t.account = yt.account AND t.startyear = @StartingYear)

Comment: Yeah, this isn't going to be a direct copy paste because I don't know exactly how you'll be using it. My goal was to produce a query which returns the data you laid out in your sample data. If you feel this answered your question, be sure to mark it as the answer 

Comment: Ok, I have testet this now on the total dataset and run into som issues. When you use this: SELECT SumProdBudget = EXP(SUM(LOG(1+yt.forecast)) OVER (ORDER BY yt.startyear)) * @StartingBudget 
I need to only select the same division and account for the running total. Now it seems like it make the sum of the total on all lines.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, because in your post you did not specify it needed to be within a specific grouping. If you want it to be within a particular grouping, try changing the `OVER` clause to something like `OVER (PARTITION BY division, account ORDER BY yt.startyear)`

Comment: Ah, thanx Chad, that was perfect :-) Works perfectly!!